# Need to remove Empty pages when subreport is returning no data (IReport)

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a subreport inside a main report on a new page due to the layout. When the subreport generates no data(sql table is empty), there is a blank page generated in the mainpage. How can i omit this empty page? please help me here..

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work around by using the `<printWhenExpression>` construct or try it with [isRemoveLineWhenBlank](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRElement.html)